# Using jQuery with DevExpress

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm trying to include jQuery in an ASP.NET web site that also uses DexExpress controls, but no matter how I include my script, the `$` function is always `anonymous` and the `jQuery` function is undefined.  I suspect the DevExpress 'plumbing' script is overriding jQuery.

Anything I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was URL resolution for scripts, not a conflict.  Using data binding expressions instead of code render blocks solved this issue.  Excerpts from my master page:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Smart Computer Solutions</title>
    <script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Header.DataBind();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JQuery.noConflict()?  This allows you to move JQuery to something other than the $ variable and resolves conflicts like this one.

Comment: I finally ditched DevExpress.  This project is way too thin on profit to spend so much learning time.

Comment: @ProfK - the technique I described above is the one I used to resolve conflicts between DevExpress and JQueryUI (and JQuery in turn), so it would have worked with minimal issue.